# reCAPTCHA v3 vs Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have a client request to add a `reCAPTCHA v3` to a form.

Client uses `Internet Explorer 8`.

Could not find any references to `Internet Explorer`'s versions compatibility.

But I have heard from my fellow workmates that doesn't work on `Internet Explorer 8` or below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reCAPTCHA V3 is currently a beta version.

There is no any documentation available for that can give the information for IE 8 support.

Based on my search, You can use the reCAPTCHA V2 with IE 8. As there is an official documentation available from Google.

Reference:

[Help for reCAPTCHA](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/?hl=en#6081889)

For more accurate information, I suggest you to post the question in reCAPTCHA support forum.